# How do I reposition draw.io swimlanes?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I originally created several swimlanes and started the workflow but need to re-arrange the order to cut out the number of connectors crossing over each other.

Answer (score 2):

Could not get the drag and drop solution to work in the pools.
But I found it was possible to reorder the swimlanes by selecting a lane in the pool and then using up- and down-arrows on the keyboard.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked reliably for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the 'pool' type shapes for example 'Horizontal Pool 2' you can individually select one of the 'lanes' (as per below)

[image]

And then drag it to another lane:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: For me, this is only working when moving a lane DOWN. Trying to drag and drop a lane into an upper position will superpose the two lanes instead of 'inserting' the lane in between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it's possible to reposition a swimlane this way:

1. click on the swimlane you want to move, in order to select it
2. click and start dragging it...
3. press the ALT key and drop the swimlane over the one in the position you want to take.

The dragged  swimlane will be inserted before the existing one.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me in the DrawIO extension for Visual Studio Code